# WiFi icon not displaying plus some WiFi networks never connecting on Ubuntu Studio 14.04

Tags: networking, wireless, disconnect

Been using Ubuntu since March 2013 and now I installed Ubuntu Studio 14.04 on notebook.

WiFi icon won't show, and while notebook connects to most of WiFi networks, it won't connect to some (not even asking for password for those) and in other cases it will connect only to go down after a while.

Some driver information follows:

```
$ lsmod | grep 8192  
amdkfd                 81920  1  
snd_hda_codec_realtek    81920  1  
rtl8192se              65536  0  
rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8192se  
rtlwifi                73728  2 rtl_pci,rtl8192se  
mac80211              724992  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8192se  
r8169                  81920  0
```

Comment: Have you been looking into `/var/log/syslog`?

Comment: Yes, did. But haven't found nothing clear. Could connect to the rebel wifi by creating the connection description manually in "Edit Connections" (right-click menu on the wifi icon, which by the way won't work so am also starting it up manually using "nm-applet &")

Answer (score 0):

Install a driver this way

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmware
```

Comment: Manually defined rebel WEP wifi, was able to connect.

Comment: Then saw your solution and tried. Install was ok. Still having shaky connections, at least with a WPA that I use quite a lot.

Comment: After a couple weeks, problem persists as follows:
1. wi-fi symbol won't display; am forcing it by 'sudo nm-applet &'
2. if i connect to a new wi-fi network, it won't ask for a password (but pointer hoover over the wi-fi symbol will say it needs a password). i need to manually add the network (guessing the parameters) for it to work.
3. sometimes connections will be solid, and sometimes shaky, not connecting or connecting for a short time. *** any ideas will be deeply appreciated ***